# How to simplify a sql with a lot of “case when then else …”

Tags: mysql, sql, database, google-bigquery, case

Run into sql code with a lot of `when`:

```
case
    when callDuration >    0 and callDuration <  30 then  1.4
    when callDuration >=  30 and callDuration <  60 then  2.3
    when callDuration >=  60 and callDuration < 120 then  3.7
    when callDuration >= 120 and callDuration < 180 then  4.5
    when callDuration >= 180 and callDuration < 240 then  5.2
    when callDuration >= 240 and callDuration < 300 then  6.1
    when callDuration >= 300 and callDuration < 360 then  7.3
    when callDuration >= 360 and callDuration < 420 then  8.4
    when callDuration >= 420 and callDuration < 480 then  9.2
    when callDuration >= 480 and callDuration < 540 then 10.1
    when callDuration >= 540 and callDuration < 600 then 11.9
    when callDuration >= 600                        then 12.3
end as duration
```

If there are 100 lines of this kinds of when and then, how to simplify it and more elegant, I can think use Jinjia Template or with a lookup table. Any better approach, not restrict by specific variant?

Comment: The lookup table is an excellent suggestion. Is there a mathematical formula to derive the results? I couldn't spot a pattern but if you are able to reduce it to a formula representation, that's another option.

Comment: just an example for maintain legacy code, and no formula.

Answer (score 4):

### Approach

I think the most elegant solution would be a lookup table (you mentioned it above).

Below is an example, but for simplicity I didn't enter all the ranges listed in your example.

### Create Data

```
create table lookupTable(
startCallDuration int,
endCallDuration int,
returnValue float);

insert into lookupTable values (0,30,1.4);
insert into lookupTable values (30,60,2.3);
insert into lookupTable values (60,120,3.7);
insert into lookupTable values (120,999999999,4.5);

create table callDuration(
callDuration int );

insert into callDuration values (30);
insert into callDuration values (60);
```

### Sql Statement

```
select returnValue from lookupTable l, callDuration c
where c.callDuration >= startCallDuration and
c.callDuration < endCallDuration;
```

### Sql Statement (Inner Join)

```
select returnValue from lookupTable l inner join callDuration c
on c.callDuration >= startCallDuration and
c.callDuration < endCallDuration;
```

SqlFiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/11009e6/3

Comment: @GMB done/updated! Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1):

*Heartily* agree! This is precisely the job for a "lookup table," which ought to *have always been* a fundamental part of the database for precisely this reason. These *"100 lines of logic"* ought to be "a 100-line lookup table." @Menelaos showed you two examples.

Now, before proceeding further, you should carefully search through the application code for ***all(!)*** such "messy examples of the old way," to be certain that all of them *exactly* match with your lookup-table replacement strategy.  This is a so-called ***highly-pervasive change*** which should be approached very carefully.

Answer (score 1):

Consider below for BigQuery

```
with lookup_table as (
  select 
    [0, 30, 60, 120, 180, 240, 300, 360, 420, 480, 540, 600] ranges,
    [1.4, 2.3, 3.7, 4.5, 5.2, 6.1, 7.3, 8.4, 9.2, 10.1, 11.9, 12.3] choice
)
select callDuration, choice[safe_offset(range_bucket(callDuration, ranges) - 1)] as duration
from your_table, lookup_table
```

if applied to sample data (your_table) like below

[image]

the output is

[image]